# Honeywell T10 manual fan mode not working

Tags: hvac, blower

I have a Honeywell T10 thermostat that will not turn the blower (all electric HVAC) in manual mode. Works fine on Auto though. The HVAC is a Rheem. I just can’t figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a wiring diagram for your HVAC unit please?

Comment: Remove the main part of the thermostat and take a picture of the base showing how all the wires are connected.

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove the thermostat panel so I can take a photo?